# Gerar numero randômico e adicionar Class no body da página de login do Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com um problema que a principio e simples, porem não faço ideia do que eu estou fazendo de errador.

a função e simples, eu quero adicionar uma class dentro do Body na pagina de login do Wordpress, eu consigo fazer isso, porem eu também quero que ao atualizar a pagina seja gerado um numero aleatório para complementar a class.

Exemplo: ao acessar a pagina e gerado uma class aleatória, digamos que seja "bg_color_2", ao atualizar a pagina o valor mude para outro numero aleatório e fique digamos "bg_color_4".

A função que eu estou utilizando e essa aqui, porem não esta funcionando.

```
function login_classes( $classes) {
    $classes[] = 'bg_color_'; // essa e a class
    $value = rand(1,5); // aqui e gerado meu numero aleatório até 5
    return $classes, $value; / onde deve retornar os valores que fique "bg_color_4"
}
add_filter( 'login_body_class', 'login_classes' );
```

Eu consigo fazer de outro jeito, o problema e que eu tenho q editar o wp-login.php do Wordpress e adicionar dentro da class do body essa função:

```
bg_color_<?php echo rand(1,5); ?>
```

E claro que isso não e uma alternativa, até porque jamais se deve alterar os arquivos do Wordpress, sem correr o risco de perde ao atualizar.

Comment: Suplementando o a pergunta, estava utilizando uma aplicação que utiliza a extensão .tpl, para usar a função rand nesse tipo de arquivo, basta usar "{1|rand:5}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa concatenar o valor e adicionar ele no $classes:

```
function login_classes($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'bg_color_' . rand(1,5);
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'login_body_class', 'login_classes' );
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, nem acredito que foi tão simples, tentei de tudo, serio mesmo...